# Woocommerce, wordpress

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart

I am developing a shop online with wordpress and woocommerce. The price of the products depends on the size of them. I use € x meters. When the costumer add one product on the cart, I update the custom price  WP-Sesseion, but when the customer add other one, the total price is not ok.
I get the price from a externar server inside of json file, and uptate it in a WP_session. Then get the price in funciton.php and update the price of the cart.

```
 function action_woocommerce_review_order_after_submit( $cart_object) {

$custom_price = WC()->session->get( 'price_project' ); // This will be your custome price
$target_product_id = WC()->session->get( 'product_id' );
foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $value ) {
if ( $value['product_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
     WC()->session->set( 'price' , $custom_price );
$value['data']->price = $custom_price;
}
}
}

do_action( 'woocommerce_after_calculate_totals', 'action_woocommerce_review_order_after_submit');
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use the hook woocommerce_before_calculate_totals instead since the cart will update the totals after you make your price adjustments in that case.